# How to sign a file with smartcard and Chilkat for Go

Tags: go, chilkat

I am using Chilkat version 9.5.0.80 with Go bindings.

I am able to sign a PDF file with a smartcard connected via USB reader on my PC

Unfortunately I cannot find the `cert.SetSmartCardPin` method so I cannot automatically sign documents without the PIN popup (Windows and Linux)

I am able to do it with C#, so I think it's just a matter of missing Go method wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point in time (8-April-2020), the Chilkat smartcard functionality is limited to the Windows operating system.  The Chilkat Go Language package is for multiple operating systems (Windows, Linux, MacOSX, etc.) and we excluded the Windows-only functions because Go does not have a preprocessor to control the inclusion of platform specific code.

We can look for solutions, but if possible, it can't happen until the next version of Chilkat is released.